# Difference b/w system calls & user calls in linux or any OS

Tags: linux, operating-system

I am searching for answer for many days but none of them solved my query. What is difference b/w system call & user call, I want to calculate USER CPU time & Kernel CPU time for printf() function in C. User cpu time is time taken by CPU to execute user routine & Kernel cpu time is time taken by cpu to execute kernel routine. My question is some where in calling printf() , In the end system call is invoked to print characters at display. I mean to say in routine printf() which part belongs to user & which part belongs to kernel. Does simple assignment statement a=b involves system call?

Answer (score 1):

A simple `a=b` statement in C does not involve system calls; this is completely executed in userspace.

In `printf()`, most of the code is executed in userspace (eg. formatting of the supplied arguments). Only for writing the final formatted text to stdout is the `write` system call invoked. You can see this with the `strace` tool which shows all system calls made by an application.

Comment: It means MOV a b is user call. If both operands are in same memory segment accessible by this process ,this will be executed in user space. Ok thanks.

Comment: Correct. AFAIK under Unix transition from user space to kernel space happens only explicitly, ie. you will see it in the assembler code (for example as SYSENTER instruction, or usually as call to a libc function which does the system call).